# The last value in list is replacing all other values while setting within loops in Groovy

Tags: groovy

EDITED QUESTION:

```
def responseTemp = [] 
def response = [:]
   loop1.each { row1 -> 
   loop2.each (row2 -> 
   loop3.each {row3 -> 
   loop4.each {row4 -> 
      response << ['field1' : 'row1.value1'] 
      response << ['field2' : 'row2.value1'] 
      response << ['field3' : 'row3.value1'] 
      responseTemp.add(response) 
      } 
     } 
    }  
   } 
println (responseTemp)
```

Expected Result is I should have all the response (mine runs 10 times) so should see all 10 response in responseTemp. But what i see if just the 10th response 10 times in responseTemp.

How can I add all response into responseTemp as we iterate and return that in the end.

Comment: Why are you reusing the names of your lists as your closure variables? Beside that, `response  << ['key' : "value"]` is going to end up with just one value in `response`, even if you run it one million times.

Comment: I am basically trying to save all the response in a list and pass it on later once the looping is done

Comment: But in trying to do so all i see is just the last response repeated the no . of times the loop has run

Comment: @ernest_k : Is there a way i can save all those response into another list so that i don't loose them while looping? And which i can use after the loop ends

Comment: You are most likely losing them because you are adding them to the same map (`response`) over and over again - yet it's totally not clear what you are after -- this code example is so far abstracted from the real problem it's hard to follow (at least for me). Could you please provide a minimal viable example (define list[123] with a few dummy values, don't add always the same `[key: "value"]` to the map but something real, and finally state what you expect the result to be given the inputs.

Comment: @cfrick - You are right, I get a new response everytime.  Every time when i get a response I am trying to add that to "result" which is just a list.. so I could get all saved in that result which I can use outside the loop. I am puzzled why that result is getting messed up and I see the last response added no. of times the loop was executed

Comment: this a my sample logic:

loop1.each { row1 ->
loop2.each (row2 -> 
loop3.each {row3 ->
loop4.each {row4 ->
  response << ['field1' : 'row1.value1']

Comment: this a my sample logic:
def responseTemp = []
loop1.each { row1 ->
         loop2.each (row2 -> 
               loop3.each {row3 ->
                      loop4.each {row4 ->
                                 response << ['field1' : 'row1.value1']
                                 response << ['field2' : 'row2.value1']
                                 response << ['field3' : 'row3.value1']
                                 responseTemp.add(response)
                       }
                  }
             }
       }

Comment: @cfrick sorry unable to format it properly.
Expected Result is I should have all the response (mine runs 10 times) so should see all 10 response in responseTemp.

But what i see if just the 10th response 10 times in responseTemp.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65327104/edit) the question

Comment: @cfrick - Edited the question. Please let me know if helps.. If not I can give you more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you hold on to your map to add to the results over all items of
your cartesian product, you will always add the same map to the result.
And since you override always the same keys, the map will contain the
items of the last iteration.

Simple solution: move the `def response` into the innermost
each/closure.

Yet you can also just not use a variable at all and a map literal instead.  E.g.

```
def responseTemp = [] 
[1,2].each{ row1 -> 
    [3,4].each{ row2 -> 
        responseTemp.add([field1: row1, field2: row2])
    }  
} 
println (responseTemp)
// → [[field1:1, field2:3], [field1:1, field2:4], [field1:2, field2:3], [field1:2, field2:4]]
```

If you prefer a more declarative way, you can also use `collectMany` on
the outer loops and finally `collect` in the innermost.  E.g.

```
def responseTemp = [1,2].collectMany{ row1 -> 
    [3,4].collectMany{ row2 -> 
        [5,6].collect{ row3 -> 
            [field1: row1, field2: row2, field3: row3]
        }  
    }  
} 
println (responseTemp)
// → [[field1:1, field2:3, field3:5], [field1:1, field2:3, field3:6], [field1:1, field2:4, field3:5], [field1:1, field2:4, field3:6], [field1:2, field2:3, field3:5], [field1:2, field2:3, field3:6], [field1:2, field2:4, field3:5], [field1:2, field2:4, field3:6]]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @cfrick